# IntelliJ Dockerfile Run/Debug Configuration: How to add local AWS credentials?

Tags: amazon-web-services, intellij-idea, dockerfile, credentials

I use IntelliJ's Dockerfile run/debug configurations alot with AWS.  I use it mainly to run my containers locally and they consume AWS services such as S3 and Secrets Manager in our test account.

We use AWS credentials (Secrets/Tokens etc) which expire every hour.  I am now passing in the credentials via environment parameters as follows:

**-e AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_ID=value** (value of the key taken from the credentials file). I'm leaving out the other two keys for brevity, but it follows the same KEY/VALUE paradigm as the preceding example.

This works, but there are a couple of problems with this.

1. I have to pass in the actual value of the credentials to the environment variables.  Not a horrible problem, but since they expire every hour, I have to update the Run/Debug config with the update values every hour.
2. Related to above, I can't figure out how to programmatically grab the credential VALUES via a call to "aws configure".

I have a Bash script that I run which refreshes the AWS credentials and stores them in my DEFAULT profile in the ".aws" folder locally.

What I'd really like to do is to have the Dockerfile Run/Debug configuration without me having to crack open the "credentials" file from ".aws" and copy/pasting the values in the the Run/Debug configuration.

Note: The Dockerfile Run/Debug configurations will not be checked into Git so there's no chance of my credentials getting inadvertantly checked in.

What I'd like to do:
I'd like to get the values of the secrets into the Dockerfile environment variable definition automatically so I don't have to keep updating the Run/Debug config manually.  When I refresh my tokens, the Dockerfile Run/Debug config would pick them up automatically.

What I've tried to do:
I've modified my local .bash profile to get the token values from the credential store using "aws configure".  That works, but the new tokens don't get refreshed automatically in the Dockerfile Run/Debug config.  If I use the "source" command run a running bash shell it does get the newest value. I think I need to do something like that in the Dockerfile Run/Debug config, but I'm not sure how.

Dev environment:
 MacBook Pro (running Mojave)
 IntelliJ (2018.3)
 AWS CLI, Docker Tools installed

Any ideas?

Comment: No workarounds for now, it's being discussed with the AWS team and they promised to submit a request at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA with the requirements for the future IntelliJ IDEA versions.

Comment: Good to know.  Thank you!